# Django - How to use an increment counter inside of template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, counter

I'm trying to have my form not display (display:none;) if the maximum number of people signed up for a specific event is reached/exceeded. signups is a model with fields eventname and fullname. I'm also using a ListView, FormView to loop through the list of events, each with a sign up form.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
<form action="/events/" class="form" method="POST" style="{% for signups in signup %}{% if signups.eventname == events.name %}*counter increment here*{% if *counter value* >= events.maximum %}display:none;{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}" id="{{ events.name }}" name="{{ events.name }}">
```

{% if signups.eventname == events.name %} checks the model signups for objects with matching eventnames so that only objects for the wanted event is counted.
This is all inside of {% for events in events_list %}{% endfor %} and consider text inside asterisks comments.

How would I do this? If you would like to see any other files or information, I will gladly edit this.

Answer (score 3):

Think you're going about ths the wrong way. Get the number of people signed up first in your *view* which you can then pass to your template as a *template variable* and make an if condition something like this:

```
{% if (signed_up_variable) < (max number) %}
    # display the form
{% endif %}
```

Although, if i recall correctly `ifequal` may be deprecated, so adjust that accordingly.

Comment: I was thinking of doing like SignUps.objects.filter(eventname=*event name in events model*).count(), but I'm not sure how I would pass {{ events.name }} for the specific event the user is trying to sign up for because I'm using a for loop in the template to list the objects in events.

Comment: Basically, is there a way to pass {{ events.name }}, which is the event name unique to that specific loop, to views.py?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need forloop.counter . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for